# how to define html5 svg polygon points to create graphics

Tags: html, svg

Hi i am trying to find out how to define the points for a polygon in HTML5

```
<svg width="300" height="200">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198"
    style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>
```

this will end up creating a Star image.
i tried to remove some points and add some arbitrary points and it doesn't create any image.i tried with three points also but it didn't worked out.

Comment: e.g. Triangle: `<svg height="210" width="500">
  <polygon points="200,10 250,190 160,210" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:1" />
</svg>` - Use this generator: http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator

Comment: hi thanks for the reply can u please explain the meaning of points="200,10 250,190 160,210" , is 200 is the starting point what is the meaning of "10 250" does 250 represent thickness

Comment: in all honesty I never tried to create SVG Polygons, but I found the explanation in the specification document, you can read about it here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#PolygonElement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The values are in pairs, each pair is an (x, y) co-ordinate of a polygon vertex.

200, 10 is 200 units away from the origin in the x direction (across) and 10 units in the y direction (down).